# Tenant Id Injection in Play framework

Tags: playframework

How to inject the tenant id in all the queries or retrieve and add tenant id in the Dao Layer?

Using Play framework and Mongo DB

```
a. Using MDC (http://yanns.github.io/blog/2014/05/04/slf4j-mapped-
   diagnostic-context-mdc-with-play-framework/)
b. Storing the tenant id on session() during login and retrieving tenant id 
   from Http.Context.Session() in Dao Layer (which we should not do)
c. Using Security context and #Redact in Mongo DB
```

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, MDC is basically a thread local and only for logging. ThreadLocal storage is certainly not ideal in the play framework. What you could do is passing the id as parameter along (potentially as implicit).

Comment: so what would be the solution rethab?

Comment: Is there a local cache in play instead of global cache (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache) for a particular request ?